# Dictionary returns undefined when searching by key

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am currently making a small, test website, and I have a function that will add an image to the innerHTML based on the input:

```
function montreImg(nomImage){
var output = document.getElementById("fileContent"/*Placeholder*/);

var images = {
    ranch : "/ressources/bungalow/ranch.jpg",
    bungalowstyle : "/ressources/bungalow/bungalow style.jpg",
    tuscan : "/ressources/bungalow/tuscan.jpg",
    farmhouse : "/ressources/bungalow/farmhouse.jpg",
    traditional1 : "/ressources/bungalow/traditional1.jpg",
    cabin : "/ressources/2etages/cabin.jpg",
    craftsman : "/ressources/2etages/craftsman.jpg",
    modern : "/ressources/2etages/modern.jpg",
    southern : "/ressources/2etages/southern.jpg",
    traditional2 : "/ressources/2etages/traditional2.jpg"
};

console.log(images.nomImage);
var img = '<img src="' + images[nomImage] + '">';
output.innerHTML += img;
}
```

Whenever I search the object by the key, it gives me undefined (in the console log) and it'll say couldn't find the image because it's searching for undefined. I originally had the keys as strings and searched with:

```
images[nomImage]
```

but that also returned undefined. I verified, and the input is of type string. I have searched for hours but couldn't find anyone who had a similar problem to me. I am not using AJAX or any other frameworks, it's pure JS and a local website.

I can't seem to find anything wrong with my code, but I am relatively new to JS, so I might be missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you console.log(images, nomImage) and verify that the value of "nomImage" actually exists in the images object?

Comment: @Ian It gives me this:
{ranch: "/ressources/bungalow/ranch.jpg", bungalowstyle: "/ressources/bungalow/bungalow style.jpg", tuscan: "tuscan.jpg", farmhouse: "/ressources/bungalow/farmhouse.jpg", traditional1: "/ressources/bungalow/traditional1.jpg", …} "tuscan
"
I'm 99% sure that the key exists.

Comment: In my testing, I am using tuscan as the key.

Comment: Try: console.log(images[nomImage]); And then call the method as a test with: montreImg('tuscan'); Works for me at jsbin: https://jsbin.com/zezomusuga/edit?js,console

Comment: @MikeCheel I tried doing it manually too, and it worked. Turns out my input had an extra space at the end for some reason, so I'll just add a .trim()

Comment: You should normalize / validate inputs when passed to functions as a best practice.

Comment: @MikeCheel How would I go about that? I'm new to programming in general. Also, the input was being taken from a text file, so maybe that could have caused it?

Comment: @AndrewPham Check that your inputs aren't null / undefined, that the type of value is what you expect, etc inside the function

Comment: @MikeCheel I'll make sure to keep this in mind in the future, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out by copying and pasting the console logs, there was an extra space in front of my input text. This drove me crazy. Sorry for posting, but I'll leave it up in case anyone runs into the same thing as me.

Here's what the input was:

```
"tuscan "
```

But it should have been:

```
"tuscan"
```

Didn't notice until I copied and pasted outside of the log.

Comment: Alright great that you fixed it yourself. Make sure to always trim your inputs ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only way the `console.log` would not print `undefined` is if you actually  have an entry in your dictionary with that key.

These are equivalent:

```js
console.log(images.nomImage)
```

```js
console.log(images['nomImage'])
```

So, what you want is quite literally on the line below that in your code, i.e.:

```js
console.log(images[nomImage])
```

... as this will extract the value of the key that nomImage holds.